# Access oracle database from another system?

Tags: oracle10g

Is it possible to access my oracle database from a separate system, other than the one on which the database is stored?
If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the tables of a distant database by using `your_table@your_database` if you configured it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access your database which is on one machine( SERVER) from other machine (CLIENT). You need to install oracle client software on the CLIENT machine and then you can establish a connection to the server database through network . You have to use sqlplus to connect or if you are using windows then you can use tools like toad which will establish a connection between your client machine and database server machine .